# How to make WordPress run a script every X time?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Today I came across an interesting issue while developing a simple script for a client. The client wanted his WooCommerce product stock to be automatically updated every day at a set time but the event simply isn't triggering. Below you can find my implementation of the script that was written in the functions.php file inside the theme's folder:

```
// UPDATE WOOCOMMERCE STOCKS AGAINST BRANDSDISTRIBUTION
function my_cron_schedules($schedules){
    if(!isset($schedules["5min"])){
        $schedules["5min"] = array(
            'interval' => 5*60,
            'display' => __('Once every 5 minutes'));
    }
    if(!isset($schedules["1min"])){
        $schedules["1min"] = array(
            'interval' => 1*60,
            'display' => __('Once every 1 minutes'));
    }
    if(!isset($schedules["30min"])){
        $schedules["30min"] = array(
            'interval' => 30*60,
            'display' => __('Once every 30 minutes'));
    }
    return $schedules;
}

add_filter('cron_schedules','my_cron_schedules');

wp_schedule_event(time(), '1min', 'my_schedule_hook');

function my_schedule_hook(){
    // do something every day

    echo "creating data.csv because i didnt find it";

    $username = 'REMOVED FOR SECURITY';
    $password = 'REMOVED FOR SECURITY';
    $header = "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($username . ':' . $password);
    $url = 'https://www.brandsdistribution.com/restful/export/api/products.csv?acceptedlocales=pt_PT';

        if (!file_exists("data.csv")) {
            $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body(wp_remote_get($url, array('headers' => $header)));
            file_put_contents("data.csv", $body);
        }

        if (($handle = fopen("data.csv", "r")) !== false) {
            fgetcsv($handle);
            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false) {
                $num = count($data);
                for ($c = 0; $c < $num; $c++) {
                    $col[$c] = esc_attr($data[$c]);
                }

                $product_id = 7;//$col[28];
                $quantity = 200;//$col[31];

            wc_update_product_stock_status($product_id, $quantity);
            }

        }

        fclose($handle);
}
```

We have it set to trigger the event every 1 minute for testing purposes. The script doesn't even seem to reach the first 'if' inside the my_schedule_hook() function.

Might it be something cron related?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You will need to use cron job or ajax

Comment: Since Woocommerce 3.5 realease, the Action Scheduler library used by the WooCommerce Subscriptions plugin and other WooCommerce plugins is now included in WooCommerce core. See it in [Features for store builders and developers](https://woocommerce.wordpress.com/2018/10/23/woocommerce-3-5-is-here/#more-5410), which is a much better solution to everithing else.

Answer (score 0):

So, wordpress Cron is not a real Cron. It depends uppon pages being visited and then this triggers the wp-cron.php. So if the update ran at a certain time point, it will only run again after the set time has passed AND someone visits the site.

You can disabled wp's Cron on wp-config (define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true)) and use your webhost's cron job to run wp-cron.php.